# Why is javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder a 'Builder'?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

Isn't it more like a Factory? It doesn't even have a `build()` method and doesn't seem to have a state based on method calls.

Answer (score 1):

All methods return an `Expression` or `Predicate`. You can chain the calls and while doing so, you build the final criteria for your query.

The criteria holds the state you are missing.

The `Expression` and `Predicate` are complex objects, build in steps from multiple sources, including other Predicates. I don't see the neccessity of a `build()` function to have a builder pattern.

As you can read in the excellent summary quoted in the comments (thanks @Mike Nakis) , the builder pattern itself references to call chaining or abstraction in a multistep creation process.

If you consider the complex creation use case, you can see the object created is the `Criteria`. To be created, it requires constraints. These are constructed using the `CriteriaBuilder`.

Comment: Absolutely. Then why is it called a builder?

Comment: @doctorgester Because someone decided to call it that way!

Comment: @doctorgester The word Builder is not strictly reserved for pure implementations of the Builder creationnal pattern.

Comment: For example, why is a `StringBuilder` called a builder?  (There is a question for that: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305504/is-stringbuilder-an-application-of-the-builder-design-pattern)